# How to save my succulent?

Tags: diagnosis, watering, succulents, sunlight

Sorry I couldn't be more specific in the title (I honestly don't even know if it's a succulent, that's my best guess), I have no clue what this thing is, but I want to keep it alive.

I had this plant for a while, since last November. It grew a little bit and seemed to be thriving in the dryness of winter. Come spring however, and it looks miserable, and it's only getting worse.

It seemed to begin after I started putting it outside, though I'm not sure if that's a coincidence. I generally watered it every 1-3 weeks the amount of 3-5 TSP, but as the ends of the leaves started to shrivel I gave it some every week. Everything I've been able to read says that an over watered succulent will look bloated, and mine is the opposite. I just stuck a popsicle stick all the way to the bottom of the pot and it came out completely clean, suggesting the soil is dry.

I really have no idea what's going on here. Here's a few pictures that will hopefully help you in helping me.
[image: plant4]
[image: plant3]
[image: plant2]
[plant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dirtt.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Transplant into fresh plain potting soil.  Pot a bit larger than the one it is in now, perhaps a clay pot, with drainage hole, 4 to  6" in diameter no larger.  4" in height.  Use just potting soil, no rock or gravel below the soil and over the drainage hole.

Purchase a boring basic fertilizer such as Osmocote extended release 14-14-14, or Dr. Earth's All Purpose at 5-5-5, use *half the prescribed amount*.  Move as close to a window as possible without direct sun.  Water only when the pot/plant feel light when you lift it.

Get basic cheapo potting soil WITHOUT gimmicks such as fertilizer or water holding sponges/gels.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a bromeliad to me, which is not a succulent. looks kind of pale indicating it could use better (more) light.